# How can we print all sub matrices of a given 2D matrix in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, submatrix

Suppose I have a matrix of size, say 5*6.
I need all the sub matrices, that is, of size 1*1, 1*2, 2*5,3*2,5*4 etc.
How do I obtain it?

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
  int arr[][] = new int[i + 1][j + 1];
  for (x = 0; x < i + 1; x++) {
   for (y = 0; y < j + 1; y++) {
    arr[x][y] = a[x][y];
    System.out.print(arr[x][y] + "  ");
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println("*********next********");
 }
}
```

This is my code till now. But this is printing the subarray of desired sizes only starting from 0,0 index.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code? Can you post what you have so far

Comment: Yes. I have attached my code.

Comment: Please post [mcve] including test case data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
public static void printMatrix (int columnStart, int rowStart, int columnSize, int rowSize, int[][] matrix) {
    if (columnStart+columnSize>matrix[0].length) return;
    if (rowStart+rowSize>matrix.length) return;
    for (int i=rowStart;i<rowStart+rowSize;i++) {
      for (int j=columnStart;j<columnStart+columnSize;j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+" ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("*********next********");
  }

  public static void printAllSubMatrices (int[][] matrix) {
    for (int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++) {
      for (int m=1;m<matrix.length-i+1;m++) {
        for (int j=0;j<matrix[0].length;j++) {
          for (int n=1;n<matrix[0].length-j+1;n++) {
            printMatrix(j, i, n, m, matrix);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    //This will print you all the 36 sub-matrices of 3X3 matrix
    printAllSubMatrices(matrix);
  }
```

Comment: But this code is not working for non-square matrices. How should we code it for M*N matrix?

Comment: I can look at it tomorrow to confirm - but I think it should work for any n*m matrix. I gave the 3x3 matrix in the main of the code as an example only. You should be able to get correct results with 3x4 matrix. If you notice an issue tell me what you see - and I'll offer a fix.

Comment: I tried it for a 2*3 matrix = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}. But it didn't display all submatrices.

Comment: Ok. I'll look again tomorrow morning.

Comment: Fixed - it was a typo in the line for (int n=1;n<matrix[0].length-j+1;n++) - which had matrix.length instead of matrix[0].length. It works now, I fixed the example in the answer. If you find it useful, I hope you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of O(n^6) Brute force .

```
int a[][]= new int [m][n];
for(int i =0 ; i<m;i++)
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
for(int r=i;i<m;i++)
for(int c=j;c<n;c++)
for(int l1=i ;l1<r;l1++)
for(int l2=j; l2<c;l2++)
 print a[l1][l2];
```